# Generating barcodes for huge amount of data

Tags: .net, barcode

I am looking for a barcode generation API for .Net that can generate barcodes for data of unlimited size (10-100 pages of text or even bigger).

I have been suing [Zen](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/) it’s all good and perfect except for the issue that I can’t create barcode for bigger data, I have spent last two weeks trying tweak some code to allow it to generate barcode images without any data size limitations but its complex and I am unable to get it right.

**Can anyone suggest a way to map unlimited ammount in the form of 2D barcodes?**

*P.S. Practical implications such as this big barcodes images not practically useful etc. are not my concerns currently, I just need to implement a system to which I can give long length of data and it can generate me its barcode image, may be an image of 1000 x 1000 pixels or higher.*

Comment: If you could describe your original problem, maybe there is a better solution than barcodes. The fact that nobody implements unlimited barcode length is a strong hint that nobody needs it. Probably because it's not a good solution to presenting large data.

Comment: representing `big documents` data as an image(barcode) which can be scanned and read. But please note that this is more of a `R & D` type of assignment so there may be no realistic practical implications for it.

Answer (score 1):

A barcode is not just encoded data. It's a tricky mathematical construct that involves a lot of formatting and meta data, so a scanner can read it without errors, independent of the range to the barcode, the angle of the scanner to the barcode or the fact that the barcode may come sideways or even upside down.

A barcode carries more meta data than actual payload. You can get a good start of understanding barcode technology [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode).

When you see a barcode scanner at a cash register, you can see it scan the barcode and suddenly all that information is there. What article was scanned, how much it costs, et cetera. That information is **not** stored in the barcode. The barcode just carries a *reference* to this data. For example the barcode carries the information "1234521653". Then the computer system upon scanning looks this number up in it's database and finds all that information and sends it to the unit attached to the scanner.

Based on that information, it simply does not make sense to put a whole book into a barcode. You would need to build your own barcode mechanism, the barcode would probably be a few kilometers long even for simple essays and a scanner would be totally new hardware that needs huge paper rolls of barcodes just like old film projectors. Your "R&D" should probably never go into "D", end with "R" and have "really dumb idea" as a research result.

Maybe if you state the problem you are trying to solve, there are better ways. But barcodes are the totally wrong tool for storing a books content. That's like asking how to use a pair of tweezers to build a house. Even for R&D purposes it's the wrong tool.

Comment: Thankyou. but as i said the conerns of scanning such a big `barcode` are not imporant in my current problem. if i give this `1234521653` to barcode generator it encodes its barcode so all i need is similiar mechanism but to which i can give abyte array long enough and it can generate its image no matter how big.

Comment: agreed that it being dumb idea and almost not practical for the `D` part but this is what i am asked to do form a client.